# How do we detect the Orientation of Image captured using CameraX if Application's default orientation is set to Portrait Mode

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

Basically, My camera app is set to Portrait Mode. However, user can take photos in Potrait or landscape by rotating the phone accordingly (The app doesnt rotate).

So my question is, how can we find the captured image orientation?

I tried using `DisplayManager.DisplayListener`, however, it works only when orientation of app happens. Since I have blocked the orientation of app to portrait mode, it doesnt get any callbacks here.

I even tried using `ExifInterface`, however, it always gives 6 as rotation.

I am looking for solution using CameraX apis.

Comment: you can use  `ImageAnalysis.setTargetRotation()` and `Preview.PreviewOutput()` to decide the rotation of the photo taken using camerax api

Comment: How do I get to know about the rotation degree to set in `ImageAnalysis.setTargetRotation()`. As mentioned in the question, the app is fixed to portrait mode and Display Manager doesnt give rotation Degree since the display doesnt rotate.

Comment: From the documentation: "You might use this when the app is locked to portrait mode—and so no reconfiguration occurs on rotation—but the photo or analysis use case needs to be aware of the current rotation of the device. For example, rotation awareness may be needed so faces are oriented correctly for face detection, or photos are set to landscape or portrait.

Although data for captured images is stored without rotating it, the Exif data contains rotation information so that gallery applications can show the image in the correct orientation after saving."

Comment: Yes you are right. `but the photo or analysis use case needs to be aware of the current rotation of the device`. So how do I get to know the current rotation?

Comment: I understood your problem, could you check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022405/6630837), I think this may help you. And try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735408/6630837) too if you are concerned about battery optimizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem also. What solved it is by using the device sensor data to get the correct orientation, then set it in my `imageCapture` object. See snippet below.

```
        orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(context) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                // Monitors orientation values to determine the target rotation value
                val rotation = if (orientation >= 45 && orientation < 135) {
                    Surface.ROTATION_270
                } else if (orientation >= 135 && orientation < 225) {
                    Surface.ROTATION_180
                } else if (orientation >= 225 && orientation < 315) {
                    Surface.ROTATION_90
                } else {
                    Surface.ROTATION_0
                }

                imageCapture?.setTargetRotation(rotation)
            }
        }
```

This is also the recommended approach from a similar issue in the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144944155

Comment: But what about the default target rotation when creating the imageCapture use case?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this same in our case ExifInterface did't work.

```
private int getImgimageOrientation(){
final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
    cursor.close();
    return orientation;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration) of camerax:

> By default, the camera rotation is set to match the default display's rotation during the creation of the use case. In this default case, CameraX produces outputs to allow the app to easily match what you would expect to see in the preview. You can change the rotation to a custom value to support multi-display devices by passing in the current display orientation when configuring use case objects or dynamically after they have been created.

You can use the default display rotation and/or the camerax metadata output combinations from [Preview.PreviewOutput()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/Preview.PreviewOutput) to create transforms for `GLSurfaceView` display.

```
val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
        .build()
```

Based on the set rotation, each use case will either rotate the image data directly or provide rotation metadata to the consumers of the non-rotated image data.

- **Preview:** Metadata output is provided to create the right transforms
  for a GLSurfaceView display using
  Preview.PreviewOutput.getRotationDegrees().
- **ImageAnalysis:** Metadata output is provided so that image buffer
  coordinates are known relative to display coordinates. The analyze()
  method provides a rotationDegrees parameter representing the rotation
  that needs to be applied to the image analysis data to match the
  viewfinder.
- **ImageCapture:** The image Exif metadata will be altered to note the
  rotation setting.