# Android service doesn't rebind to camera when respawned

Tags: android-service, android-lifecycle, android-camera2, android-camerax, foreground-service

I run a service that analyzes frames in the foreground. It works fine from the moment I start the service until it gets killed. From that moment, when it respawns, I don't see the same message as before (saying X App is using your camera), although I see the foreground notification.

How can I fix this, so that when it respawns, it doesn't stop analyzing frames?

##### Starting the service

```java
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        Button btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, StartService.class);
                Utils.requestCameraPermission(getApplicationContext(), this);
                this.startService(serviceIntent);
        });
```

##### StartService

```java
public class StartService extends LifecycleService {
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private FrameAnalyzer frameAnalyzer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        frameAnalyzer = new FrameAnalyzer(...);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ServiceApp.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.service_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.test_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
        // Add listener for Camera Provider
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                CameraBinder binder = new CameraBinder(cameraProvider, getApplicationContext(), frameAnalyzer);
                binder.setUp(this);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                // This should never be reached.
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        super.onBind(intent);
        return null;
    }
}
```

##### Camera binding

```java
public class CameraBinder implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private final ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider;
    private final Context context;
    private final ImageAnalyzer imageAnalyzer;

    public CameraBinder(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider,
                        Context context, ImageAnalyzer imageAnalyzer) {
        this.cameraProvider = cameraProvider;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageAnalyzer = imageAnalyzer;
    }

    public void setUp(final LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        // Choose the camera by requiring a lens facing
        final int lens = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(lens)
                .build();
        // Image Analysis use case
        // Use cases
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888)
                .build();
        // Get orientation
        // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894580/4544940
        OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(context) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                int rotation;

                // Monitors orientation values to determine the target rotation value
                if (orientation >= 45 && orientation < 135) {
                    rotation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
                } else if (orientation >= 135 && orientation < 225) {
                    rotation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
                } else if (orientation >= 225 && orientation < 315) {
                    rotation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
                } else {
                    rotation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
                }

                // Updates target rotation value to {@link ImageAnalysis}
                imageAnalysis.setTargetRotation(rotation);
            }
        };
        orientationEventListener.enable();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Runnable::run, this);
        // Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis);
    }

    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
        if (image.getImageInfo().getTimestamp() % 10 == 0) {
            this.imageAnalyzer.run(image);
        }
        image.close();
    }
}
```

##### Versions

```
dependencies {
    def camerax_version = "1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha30"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha30"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions being logged from the addListener Runnable? ListenableFuture will catch these and log them, so it is possible that you have missed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and accesses the camera or microphone in a foreground service, declare the camera or microphone foreground service types, respectively, as attributes of your  component. [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types).

Adding this attribute to my service component in the `AndroidManifest.xml` worked:

```xml
<manifest>
    ...
    <service ... android:foregroundServiceType="camera" />
</manifest>
```